# wildfly 10 final: Error invoking timeout for timer

Tags: timer, timeout, wildfly

i have

```
@Stateless
public class TimerMonitoraggioDatabase {

    @Schedule(hour="5", minute="10", dayOfWeek="Mon-Fri",
      dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", info="MyTimer", persistent=false)
    private void scheduledTimeout(final Timer t) {
```

but if the activity exceeds 10 minutes, i have this error (first problem):

> 2017-03-20 05:20:51,097 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default -
>   1) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action
>   0:ffff0a93a0e9:-c2465a:58cbcab4:37e3 2017-03-20 05:20:51,099 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (EJB default - 1) WFLYEJB0020: Error
>   invoking timeout for timer: [id=e2ecbbbf-f339-431d-a031-4f02ea8f67fb
>   timedObjectId=Utopia-ear.Utopia-ejb.TimerMonitoraggioDatabase
>   auto-timer?:true persistent?:false
>   timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@188c2824
>   initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0
>   nextExpiration=Tue Mar 21 05:10:00 CET 2017 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT
>   info=MyTimer]: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException:
>   Transaction rolled back
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:137)
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)

and then starts the timer again (second problem ?) without throw the excption at the end of 10 minutes

Comment: i need e.g.

@AccessTimeout(value = 30, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES) 

?

Comment: no solution to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem with Wildfly 10.

Since @Schedule is just a short and easy way to package an implicit EJB Timer with a @Timeout method, all other EJB Timer restrictions apply.

I am no expert on EJB, but it seems that there is a default timeout, when the @Schedule method is expected to finish - which seems quite short (i.e. mere minutes).
Additionally - from empirical evidence - it looks like if the timout is reached, it tries to trigger the method again (hence the second run after the first terminates).

I read that you can configure the default timeout directly in JBoss, but this was no option for me - so I did not persue this lead ([JBoss transaction timeout setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184844/jboss-transaction-timeout-setting)).

What I did was setting the timeout for the @Schedule method manually.
Since Wildfly 10 is using EJB3 as default, make sure that you use the EJB3 version of the TransactionTimeout annotation.

If not already implicit, please add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now you can set a timout just for your @Schedule method, like:

```
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout:

@Schedule(hour="5", minute="10", dayOfWeek="Mon-Fri",
      dayOfMonth="*", month="*", year="*", info="MyTimer", persistent=false)
@TransactionTimeout(value = 23, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
private void scheduledTimeout(final Timer t) {
```

Comment: Updated answer to a more detailed version.